# Heroku import error from python file in react app

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, heroku

I have a React app deployed with Heroku. It uses a Python scraper script called scraper.py that gets data from a site and outputs it to a json file in the local directory. This json file is pulled into my react app and used to render certain pieces of it. I'm trying to schedule this scraper script to run each day by using heroku's scheduler functionality and I'm testing it first using

```
heroku run python src/scraper.py
```

in the vscode terminal but I get an import error within the scraper.py file when I run this command. Here's the error and a snippet from the scraper file:

```
File "src/scraper.py", line 1, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

First few lines of scraper.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver // error occurs here
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
from datetime import date
import time
```

I can't seem to figure out how to solve this. I've tried

```
 heroku run pip install selenium
```

but I get an error stating

```
pip: command not found
```

I've also tried using the python buildpack in heroku but that crashed my app. The buildpack I'm using now is https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
and I'm not using the standard nodejs buildpack in heroku because it crashes my app for some reason. The only alternative I can think of right now is to rewrite my scraper from python to js but if there's a way around this I'd greatly prefer not to rewrite the scraper. Anyone know how I might solve this?

Comment: Can you please run this - 'pip install -U selenium' and try again.

Comment: When running this I get the same error as described above, pip: command not found

Comment: Check these two items are present in your 'app' folder and you have used the same in selenium script.   CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = /app/.chromedriver/bin/ ---> https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN = /app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome ---> https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

Comment: I added the two buildpacks you mentioned to my Heroku app then tried running the script in heroku again and it still fails stating "no module named selenium". Do I need to set any variable within Heroku itself or did I just need to add those buildpacks to my app?

Comment: Yes, we have to do that. This will help you -> [YoutubeLink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfdNIOYGYVI)

Comment: I appreciate it but I don't think this will work for me. This way would require me to make a new python app with just my script then I'd have to make a backend to communicate between the react app and the python app and I'd rather avoid that for how simplistic my project is. Any other ideas?